# PHP/MySQL Not updating DB from form anymore

Tags: php, mysql

I have been working on a program for a job interview coming up soon, and I was nearing the completion of the program which had everything running the way I needed it to... but then my computer crashed. When I opened up the files again, everything was the same, nothing changed, all my changes were saved before it crashed. Only thing is, now my MySQL table doesn't get the data sent to it from the INSERT code. Is there something I can do to make this work?

I have tried creating a new database, a different table, restarting my computers, restarting Chrome, everything.... I can't get it and I'm desperate at this point.

Please see the code below...

```
// Connect to the database.
$link2 = mysqli_connect("localhost", "cl60-booking", "XXXXXXX", "cl60-booking");

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {

    die ("There was an error connecting to the database");

}
```

// Update the bookings DB with the user's hotel room.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO booking
          (`beds`, `baths`, `booked`, `checkInDate`, `checkOutDate`) 
          VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link2, 
                 $_POST['bedNumber'])."', 
                 '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link2, $_POST['bathNumber'])."', 
                 'Yes', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link2, 
                 $_POST['checkIn'])."',
                 '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link2, 
                 $_POST['checkOut'])."')";
```

Comment: What errors you are getting ?

Comment: That's the problem, I'm not getting any errors. It's saying the code is fine (and it was working before it crashed). Is there anything that could have effected the actual database rather than the code?

Comment: Nowhere do we see if and how you are executing the query. Plus if those post arrays have values

Comment: Try running the query manually in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: The post arrays are generated from the form that I didn't include in the question..

Comment: @Kyle1323  Would you please check  your code that you have written : mysqli_query($query);

Comment: You should really be using prepared statements. If anything it will make your code look a lot cleaner.

Comment: Then I for one cannot help you till we know exactly which animals we are dealing with, good luck.

Comment: @naf4me where would I put that code? Right above what I have?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I don't have access to the code right now, but the names of them are the post variables I've got. Beds & baths are int, booked is text, check in and check out are dates.

Comment: @Kyle1323 , after this line: $query = "INSERT INTO booking
          (`beds`, `baths`, `booked`, `checkInDate`, `checkOutDate`) 
          VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link2, 
                 $_POST['bedNumber'])."', 
                 '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link2, $_POST['bathNumber'])."', 
                 'Yes', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link2, 
                 $_POST['checkIn'])."',
                 '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link2, 
                 $_POST['checkOut'])."')";

Comment: I added that code and I adjusted the code that was adjusted here, and still not working..

Comment: @naf4me I get this error from that code mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given

Comment: do `mysqli_query($link2, $query);`

Comment: Oh, I was little bit wrong in this code. It would be like: mysqli_query($link2, $query)

Comment: Thank you, I will add that when I get a second- I'm headed to work now. Hopefully that works

Comment: Could it be a problem that I have two mysqli connect segments?

Comment: @naf4me thanks so much man! It worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code segment :

```
mysqli_query($link2, $query);
```